# Dúvida sobre HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http, post, http-request

Estou tentando enviar SMS atraves de um WebService.

Para enviar um único SMS é simples. Basta utilizar a URL nesse formato:

```
https://xxxxx.com/sendMessage?messageText=mensagemdeteste&destination=552199998888&key=XXXX
```

Porém segundo a documentação do WebService eu consigo enviar vários ao mesmo tempo com esse formato de URL:

```
https://xxxxx.com/sendMessageBatch?messageText=mensagemdeteste&key=XXXX
```

Ele diz que eu devo adicionar os numeros no BODY do HTTP POST:

> This option allows one message to be sent to more than one phone
>   number. Destination numbers need to be in the body of the HTTP POST.
>
> The body of the POST should be composed of lines containing the
>   destination phone numbers (line breaks only as separators):

```
destination1\\n<destination2>\\n<destination3>\\n<destinationN>
```

Mas como funciona isso?? Eu posso mexer nesse body somente via servidor, via C# por exemplo??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível em C#. Seu código se pareceria com o seguinte sample:

```
var destinos = "5555-5555\n5555-5556\n5555-9999"; //<-Números que receberão a msg

byte[] buffer= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(destinos);

var webReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxx.com/sendMessageBatch?messageText=mensagemdeteste&key=XXXX");

webReq.Method = "POST";
// webReq.ContentType = "content-type"; <- caso necessário
webReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

var reqStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Close();

var webResp = (HttpWebResponse) webReq.GetResponse();
```

Um código similar em jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxx.com/sendMessageBatch?messageText=mensagemdeteste&key=XXXX',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '5555-5555\n5555-5556\n5555-9999',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                //Caso sua operação tenha sido bem-sucedida
            }
        }
```

Comment: Legal, então só pra complementar... A url pode enviar parametros, isso é uma coisa, e o body do http post é outra coisa e pode ser modificada através de uma linguagem de servidor. É mais ou menos isso?

Comment: Mas o tal do body, somente posso modificar via servidor? E baseado no meu exemplo o Content Type seria necessário?

Comment: Muito obrigado! Acho interessante complementar a resposta com essas observações, mas fique a vontade!

Comment: se eu quiser colocar os parametros da url dentro do "data:" junto com os numeros é possivel?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Tecnicamente é possível. Se irá funcionar ou não, depende da implementação no lado do provedor deste serviço.

Comment: OnoSendai, webReq.GetRequestStream() me traz um objeto json. Mas vi na documentação que se eu quiser posso retornar em xml atraves do "application/xml". Sabe como posso obrigar ele a me trazer em xml?

Comment: Era isso mesmo!!

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Que bom, fico feliz que tenha funcionado - e agradeço a generosidade. =)

Answer (score 2):

Desde o lançamento do C# 4.0, é standard usar o [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (parte do nuget [`Microsoft.Net.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)) para pedidos web. Esta classe cria uma API unificada para enviar/receber `HttpRequestMessage`s e `HttpResponseMessage`s.

```
string[] destinos = {"destino1", "destino2", "destino3"};
var destinosStr = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, destinos);

var content = new StringContent(destinosStr);
var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://xxxxx.com/sendMessageBatch?messageText=mensagemdeteste&key=XXXX", content);
```

A API é muito mais *clean* e fácil de usar do que a API do `WebRequest`. Não é preciso trabalhar com buffers e byte arrays, e suporta tarefas assíncronas .